# Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord: table with foreign keys in more than one other table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and I'm trying to model my table relationships.

To simplify the problem, let's say I have 3 tables:
-- Customer (id, address_id, ...)
-- Employee (id, address_id, ...)
-- Address (id, ...)

Would the Address model have the following?

```
has_one :customer
has_one :employee
```

I know this is true in the case of a single relationship, but I couldn't find any examples where there were two "has_one" relationships like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use polymorphic associations as shown below.

```
# Address model
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :addressable, :polymorphic => true
end

# Customer model
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address, :as => :addressable
end

# Employee model
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address, :as => :addressable
end

# Migration script for `addresses` table
class CreateAddresses < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :addresses, :force => true do |t|
      t.references :addressable, :polymorphic => true, :null => false

      # add other address fields

      t.timestamps      
    end

    add_index :addresses, ["addressable_id", "addressable_type"], :name => "fk_addressable"

end
```

Now you can do the following:

```
customer = Customer.new
customer.address = Address.new(:street => "ABC", :city => "SF", :zip => "46646")
customer.save
```

OR

```
employee = Employee.last
print employee.address.street
```

Comment: Wow, I definitely haven't made it that far in the guides.  One question, though.  From what I've read, the "belongs_to" association should be on the table with the foreign key (ie, Employee and Customer) and the "has_one" association should be on the primary key table.  But in your example above, you've done the opposite.  Is that something particular to polymorphic associations?

Comment: The `Employee` and  the `Customer` models have the primary key(hence `has_one` in these model) and `Address` model has the foreign key(hence `belongs_to` in this model).